# Undefined reference to a function defined in a header file in C

Tags: c, header, undefined

This may seem a question already asked but I

- found no specific info about my case, e.g. there was something that I've already done
- fail to compile a program properly despite including all files and writing a hopefully normal header files and including them wherever I need them

My code in `app.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "adding_tasks.h"
#include "viewing_tasks.h"
#include "removing_tasks.h"
#include "completing_tasks.h"
#include "buffer_cleaning.h"

int main()
{   
...
return 0;
}
```

My code from `completing_tasks.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "buffer_cleaning.h"
#include "completing_tasks.h"

void task_complete(char ***all_tasks, int *num_tasks)
{
...
}
```

My `completing_tasks.h` just to ensure it is done properly and I'm not blind:

```
#ifndef COMPLETING_TASKS_H
#define COMPLETING_TASKS_H

void task_complete(char ***all_tasks, int *num_tasks);

#endif
```

The traceback I get:

```
app.c:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `clear_input_buffer'
/usr/bin/ld: app.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `update_task_list'
/usr/bin/ld: app.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `task_view'
/usr/bin/ld: app.c:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `task_remove'
/usr/bin/ld: app.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `task_complete'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The way I compile it all:

```
gcc -o app app.c adding_tasks.c completing_tasks.c removing_tasks.c buffer_cleaning.c
```

There go the questions:

- Do I have any obvious mistakes that make me look like a fool here?
- If not, what is the reason of such behaviour?
- Can this stem from recursion with `buffer_cleaning.h`? If so, what do I do to prevent it if I need it in all of these files?
- How can I improve the code so that it perhaps might start working or at least giving me another error?

I am ready to provide more code snippets if needed.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing all of the code. Start with the first issue, where is `clear_input_buffer`? Narrow the problem down to 1 header and two c files, comment out anything that uses anything else and get that working, then add another, etc.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thanks, I'll try that, I suppose. The issue is unclear to me

Comment: Does it work to do `gcc -c $i.c` (for appropriate values of i) and then `gcc -o app *.o`?

Comment: Check your header guards to make sure they are all correct and unique.

Comment: If references to other files are removed this compiles cleanly.  Please update your question to include a [mcve] that others can compile *as is* and get the same error you do.

Comment: @stark these are linker errors, the guards would not cause these.

Comment: A "traceback" is a runtime error report showing the call path to where an error occurred - usually in an interpreted language such as Python.  That is not a traceback, it is part of a build log showing linker diagnostic messages.

Comment: Is there a .o file for each .c file you stated you passed to GCC?

Comment: Note that you've omitted the `-Werror -Wall -Wextra` options to `gcc` — you should use them to give your program a maximal chance of being correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions are not *defined* in the header, they are merely *declared* in the header.

The declaration satisfies the compiler, so the translation unit compiles without error.  However these are *linker* errors.  The linker resolves references between separately compiled translation units.

Given your stated GCC command line it is not clear at least why `task_complete` is not resolved (the only undefined symbol for which you provided the source (albeit elided).  However we have only your word for it that that is the command line that resulted in those errors.  You should post the entire build log, not just the errors.

> Do I have any obvious mistakes that make me look like a fool here?

Apart from not spotting that these are linker errors, so the code must have compiled, no, but you have not provided all the diagnostic information provided.  Provide the complete log from the GCC command line to the `ld returned 1 exit`.  Also add `-Wall -Werror` to your GCC command line.

> If not, what is the reason of such behaviour?

As explained above - they are linker errors.  Something is wrong with your link.  Either the command line is not as stated, or the listed translation units do not contain the stated code.  Have you saved the files for example.

> Can this stem from recursion with buffer_cleaning.h?

Not since you have linker rather than compiler or pre-processor errors no.

> If so, what do I do to prevent it if I need it in all of these files?

Not the problem.

> How can I improve the code so that it perhaps might start working or at least giving me another error?

It is a linker issue, not a code issue.  You have to successfully link the listed modules and those modules must contain the stated symbol *definitions*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive reply! I've figured out the problem today, actually. It's connected with compiling, I compiled not every file I have, which resulted in unexpected (well, partially expected) behaviour with not being able to see all files together. I'll refer to your answer whenever I encounter similar issues since I find it a complete and useful one.